# SQL Exception:Unable to retrieve metadata for procedure

Tags: java, php, mysql, web-services, xampp

When i put ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT in conn.prepareStatement() function Exception will arise...I don't know what to do..??Can anyone help me please..??

Here my query

```
query = "insert into " + PunchoutConstants.PJ_PUNCHOUT_REGISTRY + "(PUNCHOUT_CXML_RAWFILE,"+ "DATE_TIME_ENTERED,pj_punchout_id)values(?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
```

Comment: May be you need an extra whitespace here: `REGISTRY + "(` -> `REGISTRY + " (`

Comment: Query will works correctly when i remove ",ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT" from conn.prepareStatement() (ie) conn.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)

Comment: how can i find mysql version supports "HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT"...??

Comment: Check this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44791

Comment: *"Exception will arise"* What exception?

Comment: SQL Exception:Unable to retrieve metadata for procedure